# Unable to mount drive with NTFS partitions anymore

Tags: dual-boot, mount, ntfs

I have gone through the the other questions about mounting NTFS partitioned drives, but I have found my issues to be of a different nature. I was very happy using this SATA drive with a PCI card in Lubuntu until the day I used Win7 (dual boot, Windows used occasionally and only under demand). That day Windows tried to install the Maxtor hard drive without success. After rebooting with Lubuntu I got this:

```
Error mounting /dev/sdc5 at /media/rdsg/1304EF4B014B71D1: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sdc5" "/media/rdsg/1304EF4B014B71D1"' exited with non-zero exit status 13: Record 0 has corrupt allocation size (1024 <> 13500416)
Failed to load $MFT: Input/output error
Failed to mount '/dev/sdc5': Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.
```

And from the Terminal:

```
Mounting volume... ntfs_attr_open failed: No such file or directory
Failed to open ntfs attribute: No such file or directory
Failed to load $MFT: No such file or directory
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... ntfs_attr_open failed: No such file or directory
Failed to open ntfs attribute: No such file or directory
Failed to load $MFT: No such file or directory
FAILED
Failed to startup volume: No such file or directory
Checking for self-located MFT segment... OK
ntfs_attr_open failed: No such file or directory
Failed to open ntfs attribute: No such file or directory
Failed to load $MFT: No such file or directory
Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk.
```

I have run chkdsk in Windows, but it's of no use because there's no way to mount it.

Is there a solution? There's important data in this drive which I wouldn't like to loose.

I'll appreciate any kind of help to fix this.

Roberto

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu is capable of reading and writing files stored on Windows formatted partitions. These partitions are normally formatted with NTFS, but are sometimes formatted with FAT32. You will also see FAT16 on other devices.

You must do a manual configuration to be able to mount your NTFS partititons : 
here is the link for solution : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions